# What will a Spring Bean annotated with @Configurable behave when a "new" operator applies on its constructor?

Tags: spring, java-11, spring-annotations

I have a Java class, say, XYZ, is annotated with @Configurable. In the Spring configuration, it's also defined as something like:

```
<bean class="XYZ", scope="prototype">
  <property name="pro1", ref="ref1"/>
  <property name="pro2", ref="ref2"/>
  <property name="pro3", ref="ref3"/>
</bean>
```

I noticed in the code (not mine!) XYZ is instantiated using traditional "new" operator on its constructor:

```
xyz = new XYZ()
```

the constructor doesn't include any settings of its properties. However, it seemed to work in a old Spring framework, say version 3, in the sense that the properties were all set, indicating that the bean definition was picked up by Spring.

When we upgrade Spring to 5, the aforementioned route seems not working - while the class was instantiated (by the new operator), the properties were all null.

It's somehow mysterious to me, can someone help explain? The Java is 11 and Spring is 5.6.